# Supported APIs error in windows certification kit

Tags: api, window, app-certification-kit, wack

I am developing windows 8 application, when i tested the app with windows certification kit,it was throwing an error of having APIs that is not supported for this application type like below,

API System.Reflection.CustomAttributeNamedArgument.get_MemberInfo in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.MSAppContainerAdapter.dll calls this API.

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you're including test projects in the build. Try removing references to the test project and exclude it from the build and see if you still get the error.

Comment: I deleted all the un-necessary projects but I still get the same errors, I am using Facebook, bing maps SDKs if that's matters

Comment: Are you using this version of the sdk? http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bb764f67-6b2c-4e14-b2d3-17477ae1eaca

Comment: Yes,

I copied below sample of the errors if you can help out,

API System.Diagnostics.TraceLevel in SYSTEM, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. vstest.executionengine.appcontainer.exe calls this API.
API System.Diagnostics.TraceLevel in SYSTEM, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. vstest.executionengine.appcontainer.exe calls this API.

All I see is the conflict in system. libraries.

Comment: Is your project being compiled with debug symbols turned on, or in some sort of debug configuration?

Comment: I am new at windows 8 development, How can I make sure of such a thing ?